# Duda sobre ejercicio de recursividad de C++

Tags: c++, recursión, binario

Tengo un ejercicio en el que hay que cambiar la base de decimal a binario, octal y hexadecimal. Estoy empezando y no se muy bien qué falla en este código, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería (hay que usar recursividad para resolverlo). El código me sirve para para binario y para números pequeños, pero cuando pruebo números mas grandes el octal y el hexadecimal me dan números que no corresponden a los resultados.

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void binary(int n){
    if(n>0){
        binary(n/2);
        cout<<n%2;
    }
}
void octal(int n){
    if(n>0){
        binary(n/8);
        cout<<(n%8);
    }
}
void hexa(int n){
    if(n>0){
        binary(n/16);
        if(n%16==10) cout<<"A";
        else if(n%16==11) cout<<"B";
        else if(n%16==12) cout<<"C";
        else if(n%16==13) cout<<"D";
        else if(n%16==14) cout<<"E";
        else if(n%16==15) cout<<"F";
        else cout<<n%16;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0) cout<<n<<" = 0, 0, 0"<<endl;
    else{
        cout<<n<<" = ";
        binary(n);
        cout<<", ";
        octal(n);
        cout<<", ";
        hexa(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la función `octal` y en la funcion `hexa` estás haciendo la recursividad con la función `binary`.

Cada función recursiva se debe llamar a sí misma, por lo que `hexa` debe llamar a `hexa` y `octal` a `octal`. El resultado sería este:

```
void octal(int n){
    if(n>0){
        octal(n/8); // <-----
        cout<<(n%8);
    }
}

void hexa(int n){
    if(n>0){
        hexa(n/16); // <-----
        if(n%16==10) cout<<"A";
        else if(n%16==11) cout<<"B";
        else if(n%16==12) cout<<"C";
        else if(n%16==13) cout<<"D";
        else if(n%16==14) cout<<"E";
        else if(n%16==15) cout<<"F";
        else cout<<n%16;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has resuelto la duda!

Comment: @AndresEduardoBercowsky si esta respuesta resuelve tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución

Answer (score 3):

Me gustaría complementar la excelente respuesta de [ordago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/307868/2742) con un consejo:

Sigue [el principio DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) (la fuente es Wikipedia, el resaltado mío):

> El principio No te repitas (en inglés Don't Repeat Yourself o DRY, también conocido como Una vez y sólo una) es una filosofía de definición de procesos que promueve la reducción de la duplicación especialmente en [computación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computaci%C3%B3n). Según este principio toda "pieza de [información](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informaci%C3%B3n)" nunca debería ser duplicada debido a que **la duplicación incrementa la dificultad en los cambios y evolución posterior, puede perjudicar la claridad y crear un espacio para posibles [inconsistencias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistencia_l%C3%B3gica)**.

Sigiuendo el principio DRY tu código será menos propenso a errores como el que has sufrido. Todas tus funciones son en realidad una sola: *mostrar en número en la base numérica X*, si escribes menos código es menos probable que cometas errores y los que cometas serán más fáciles de localizar. Te aconsejo cambiar tus tres funciones por:

```
char digito[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

template <int base>
void convierte_a_base(int valor)
{
    static_assert(base <= 16, "Solo hasta base 16");
    if (valor)
    {
        convierte_a_base<base>(valor / base);
        std::cout << digito[valor % base];
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBdb4IwFIav6a84cVmKicuAOeYETfbh/sAunSFd6bQJtKQUbgy/nfWgW7J5Ybx5Lk7ft89peVXdbDnv@yupeNHkAlKpa2sEK5eE8B0zkMuttHq92dOAToCGiAhxh5gi7hEx4gExQzwinhDPiBfEK2KFeKNdQogVZVUwi1Jl4ZPVYklaLXPgWrVSGCsyluHYx/OWFdqMyZ54tWVW8ozVtcv4GIB0AWE8gdG7LjTsmEsM97nhaJwQT36Bf@x77gLvvyAd5IcI3A5VrDlTPp9z3VhI05@fOISuh9DGhTrSEYILlkwqf1jwd11YwDRymRNfdJSh5Y@Efijqvua0Mbu4EQaXV@JzFSNsYxQEiXt1338D)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque el código sea un poco avanzado para mi nivel, entiendo a lo que te refieres así que gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si te fijas no es tan avanzado @AndresEduardoBercowsky , es sólo una función :P

Comment: Lo se pero ahora mismo estoy en un nivel muy básico, no hemos empezado vectores aún jajaja. Pero me ha servido tu respuesta porque veo que todo el código que he implementado se puede optimizar con la función que has usado.